# Drop all partitions from redshift for an external table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to drop all the partitions on an external table in a redshift cluster. I am unable to find an easy way to do it. I am currently doing this by running a dynamic query to select the dates from the table and concatenating it with the drop logic and taking the result set and running it separately like this

`select 'ALTER TABLE procore_iad_ext.active_histories DROP PARTITION (values='''||rtrim(ltrim(values, '["'),'"]') ||''');' from svv_external_partitions
where tablename = 'xyz';`

values looks like this ->`["2009-03-10"]`

Looking for a simpler direct solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use drop table and recreate it, that will be much faster than dropping partitions.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this would be to drop the table itself.  As long as you have the DDL to recreate the table and don't mind dropping *all* partitions, just `DROP TABLE <schemaname>.<tablename>;` then recreate the table.  The new table will not have any partitions.

Answer (score -3):

Please check out the Glue catalog. It provides a UI to easily delete the tables/partitions etc.